# Spring Boot 2 Webflux benchmark is terrible compared to asp .net core 2

Tags: asp.net, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot 2 Webflux benchmark is terrible, what I do wrong? My machine is a new macbook pro.

Spring Boot 2 M6 benchmark (logs disabled)

```
 wrk -t8 -c1024 --timeout 10 http://localhost:8080/api/values/1
    Running 10s test @ http://localhost:8080/api/values/1
      8 threads and 1024 connections
      Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
        Latency    65.35ms  225.96ms   3.32s    97.16%
        Req/Sec     0.86k   329.15     1.78k    73.01%
      58374 requests in 10.09s, 6.01MB read
      Socket errors: connect 781, read 223, write 0, timeout 0
    Requests/sec:   5785.15
    Transfer/sec:    610.18KB
```

ASP .net Core 2 (logs disabled)

```
wrk -t8 -c1024 --timeout 10 http://localhost:5000/api/values/1
Running 10s test @ http://localhost:5000/api/values/1
  8 threads and 1024 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     5.66ms   10.37ms 286.49ms   98.91%
    Req/Sec     8.84k     7.72k   23.10k    62.05%
  413298 requests in 10.06s, 85.53MB read
  Socket errors: connect 781, read 238, write 3, timeout 0
Requests/sec:  41092.22
Transfer/sec:      8.50MB
```

I use starter configurations from the box.
And  simple endpoints:

JAVA

```
 @GetMapping(value="/{id}",produces = "application/json")
    public Mono<String> getValue(@PathVariable Long id)
    {
        return Mono.just("value");
    }
}
```

C#

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            return Ok("value");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2 M7  fixed this issue.

But it's still much slower than ASP .NET Core 2

ASP .NET CORE Requests/sec: ~ 65000.00

Spring Boot 2 M7 Requests/sec: ~ 28000.00

Using MVC (no database, only a simple controller returning text)

Comment: Have you tried using Netty as the backend server of Spring Boot instead of the default tomcat?

Comment: 2.0.0 Uses net but it's still slower than .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

What's your config? I ran spring boot v3.0(default) + webflux vs ASP.NET minimal and both maxed out around 4.7k req/s calling the following simple and stupid Hello endpoint:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 10 http://localhost:8080/hello
```